# How to deploy ASP.NET MVC application to IIS server from Visual Studio 2015 without SSMS

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2015, web-deployment

I have an ASP.NET MVC application on Visual Studio 2015. I deployed the app locally to IIS Server. It runs simply but when I click on the Login Button, I get an error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.

I don't have SSMS but I made SQL Server `.mdf` file in `App_Data` using Visual Studio. Do I need to install SSMS or there is any other way?

PS. I don't have 'Microsoft Sql Server Browser' in Services

I also tried changing the connection string with `|DataDirectory|` path

[image: Error of Network-Related instance]

Comment: If you want to use a SQL Server database (a `.mdf` file), - you **must have** SQL Server **ENGINE** (not SSMS) installed on that machine - or put your database on a server that has SQL Server installed.

Comment: To use `.mdf` file as data source, database engine is required. At least SQLExpress need to be installed on the machine where you are trying to  access the `.mdf` file...